# What is meant by the "Leading Log Approximation" in the context of the steep rise in gluon distribution at small bjorken x?

Tags: particle-physics, scattering, quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

I am taking a course in QCD, and we're learning about Regge Theory, Pomeron exchange and structure functions.

I want to know what is meant by the leading log approximation in the context of the gluon distribution function. I take it has something to do with a very steep rise observed in the $F_2(x, Q^2)$ structure function, whereas Regge theory would predict a levelling off of $F_2$ at small x.

**What I think I Know**

- The optical theorem gives the cross section for some deep inelastic scattering process $ab \to X$: $\sigma(ab \to X) = \sum_i C^{ab} S_{ab}^{\alpha_i - 1}$, where $C^{ab}$ is a constant and $S_{ab}^{\alpha_i -1}$ is the centre of mass energy squared to the power $\alpha_i -1$. $\alpha_i$ is again a constant. The sum is over all possible virtual exchanges in the DIS process.
- Since bjorken $x = Q^2/S$, small $x$ corresponds to large $S$
- This means the cross section for the virtual exchange is related to $x$ via: $\sigma(V^*p\to X) \propto x^{1-\alpha_i}$
- Regge Theory predicts mesons and baryon spins are proportional to $M^2$. They can be plotted on a  linear trajectory of spin vs $M^2$ , and the y-intercept of each line gives $\alpha_i$
- Pomeron exchange dominates at small $x$, with $\alpha_{pom} = 0.08$. The cross section is : $\sigma(V^*p \to X) \propto x^{1-0.08} = x^{0.92}$
- Since $x^{0.92} \approx x^1$, it was predicted that the structure function $F_2(x, Q^2)$ should level off at small $x$.
- This levelling off was not observed - in fact, it spikes up rapidly at small $x$ (demonstrated in HERA experimental data).

**My Question**

Our professor then said this spike is due to the gluon distribution, and it has problems for QCD calculations done using the leading log approximation.

- What does any of this have to do with gluons? How do gluons come into the $F_2(x, Q^2)$ structure function?
- What is the leading log approximation? I have seen this as a power series expansion of log terms, but unsure what is being expanded here, or why.